# How to search the file directory correctly with Python for specific details

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am new to Python and trying to figure out where I am going wrong in my current program. I am trying to write it so that it will check for a specific text file ("HomeInventory.txt") and perform different tasks based on if it does or does not exist. For example, if it does exist, then it would ideally ask the user if they want to add to the data already there and if it doesn't, then ask them if they want to create a new file. I thought what I had was getting my close, but it never seems to recognize that the file does exist. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

tupleRow = ( "","" )
tupleTable = ()
while(True):

  # Obtain user input (2 different variables)
  nameVal = str(input("Enter the name of a household item: "))

  inputName = str(nameVal).upper()

  inputValue = float(input("Enter the value of your item: "))

  # Format values entered to appear like currency
  # NOTE: Because I use float as input, I only need one "0"
  # at the end

  tempVal = str(inputValue)
  finalVal = "$" + tempVal + "0"

  # Stores each new input into it's correct tuple
  tupleRow = (inputName, finalVal)

  # 2. Ask the user for new entries and stores
  #    them in the 2-dimensional Tuple.

  continueMsg = str(input("Do you have more items to enter? Y/N: ").upper())

  if(continueMsg == "Y"):
        continue
  else:
        break

tupleTable += tupleRow
myFile = Path("%~dp0HomeInventory.txt")

if(myFile.is_file() == False):

  createFile = str(input("HomeInventory.txt does not exist yet, do you want to create it? Y/N: ").upper())

  if(createFile == "Y"):

        objFile = open("HomeInventory.txt", "a+")
        # Conditional Header
        for line in objFile:

              if ("Item, Value" in line):
                    objFile.write(str(tupleTable).strip("(" ")" "'" "'"))
                    objFile.close()
              else:
                    row0 = str("Item, Value")
                    objFile.write(str(row0 + '\n'))
                    objFile.write(str(tupleTable).strip("(" ")" "'" "'"))
                    objFile.close()

  else:
        print("Y'all come back later. Y'hear? ")

elif(myFile.is_file() == True):

  overrideMsg = str(input("HomeInventory.txt already exists. Save new data here? Y/N: ").upper())

  if(overrideMsg == "Y"):
        objFile = open("HomeInventory.txt", "a")

        # Conditional Header
        for line in objFile:

              if ("Item, Value" in line):
                    objFile.write(str(tupleTable).strip("(" ")" "'" "'"))
                    objFile.close()
              else:
                    row0 = str("Item, Value")
                    objFile.write(str(row0 + '\n'))
                    objFile.write(str(tupleTable).strip("(" ")" "'" "'"))
                    objFile.close()

  else:
        print("Y'all come back later. Y'hear? ")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile('../index.html'):
    print "available";
else:
    print "not available";
```

Just imagine a file index.html that is available in parent folder. For that we can check like this.
and in case the file in the same directory like script then code would be like this

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile('index.html'):
    print "available";
else:
    print "not available";
```

I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use os module for it

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(full_path_to_file):
```

Comment: the `Path` also do the same  job , you can see the that in the answer to the question in that link you have given. possibly the issue with path string.